# Is "operator" part of the C++ standard library?

Tags: c++

I was making a calculator, this is one of my files:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

float getInfo()
{
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    float input{};
    std::cin >> input;

    return input;
}

char getOperator()
{
    std::cout << "Enter an operator: ";
    char operand{};
    std::cin >> operand;

    while (operand != '+' && operand!= '-' && operand!= '*' && operand!= '/')
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid operator, enter valid operator: ";
        std::cin >> operand;
    }
    return operand;
}
```

The variable identifier *operand* used to be *operator*, however my IDE wouldn't recognize it as a variable. Hence, the question.

Comment: What specific, exact error were you getting before?

Comment: `operator` is a reserved keyword in C++.     As such, it is not available for use in anything not specified as part of the language.    Using it as the name of a variable is therefore not allowed.

Comment: Some of the comments indicate that your use of "it" is ambiguous. When you say "wouldn't recognize it as a variable", is "it" supposed to refer to "operand" or "operator"?

Comment: @yyxy-OEC-1to3 if you are returning this operator as `char`, than it will not work.

Comment: To make a question clearer, you should show the code that reproduces the error that you're asking about rather than another example that doesn't have an error.

Comment: try searching in a [C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/995714) first, or [cppreference](https://www.google.com/search?q=operator+site:en.cppreference.com)

Answer (score 2):

`operator` is a keyword, it is not part of the standard library. Your error is because you can't use keywords as variable names.

Answer (score 0):

See [the list of C++ keywords](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword). The problem is not that the identifier "operator" is part of the standard library, but that it is part of the language itself (even more fundamental than the standard library).